# EditText hint is misaligned?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

My `EditText` hint seems to be misaligned with actual `EditText`. The problem is when I try to resize it to be smaller or larger, the `hint` stays in the same position but only the size of the box changes. I have an image to show how it should look because I have a `Button` that has its text aligned like so:

[image]

As you can see, the `hint` floats sightly above the bottom of the end of the `EditText` box. If I try todecrease the size of the `EditText`, the `placeholder` stays in the same position but the size of the box, if decreased, simply covers the hint and the hint never moves. If anything, I would want the text to be aligned to the `send Button` if possible.

Here is my code:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_comments">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.cengalabs.flatui.views.FlatEditText
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:gravity="bottom|left"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:hint="Comment back!"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                flatui:fl_fieldStyle="fl_box"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

            <com.cengalabs.flatui.views.FlatButton
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="send"
                flatui:theme="@array/sea"
                flatui:fl_textAppearance="fl_light"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/send_message"
            android:id="@+id/view_comments">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try android:gravity="center_vertical"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
```

to

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Comment: Glad to help you Happy Coding :)